# CorePlot - sync ranges of 2 graphs

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I've created 2 separate plots and now I wanted to detect when user changes xRange of one of them (scrolling) and change the xRange of second plot.

I've been trying using `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` and posting notification with new range and plotID in userInfo.
Parent viewController listens to the notification and changes xRange of the second plot, BUT:
I receive lag, the second plot is "shaky" and very often it ends up with different range.
When I do it very fast, shakiness is not observed (only lag).

How can I solve this?
You can see it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6VR7rRBuCU&feature=youtu.be

In parentViewController:

```
 -(void)receivedNewRangeNotif:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSString* identifier = [userInfo objectForKey:@"identifierKey"];
    CPTPlotRange* newRange = [userInfo objectForKey:@"newRangeKey"];

    NSLog(@"receivedNewRangeNotif: %@",identifier);
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"firstItemID"]) {
        _secondItem.postNotifications = NO;
        CPTXYPlotSpace *secondPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)_secondItem.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        secondPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:newRange.length];
        _secondItem.postNotifications = YES;
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"secondItemID"]) {
        _firstItem.postNotifications = NO;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)_firstItem.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:newRange.length];
        _firstItem.postNotifications = YES;
    }
```

In plotItem:

```
- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {
    if (_postNotifications) {   
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:newRange, @"newRangeKey",
                                  self.identifier, @"identifierKey", nil];

        NSLog(@"sendingNewRangeNotif");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TODOnotifRangeChanged" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
    }
    //DLog(@"changing plotRange");

    //disables possibility to change y size
    if (CPTCoordinateY == coordinate) {
        return [self automaticYRangeWithCustomMinY:_customMinY CustomMaxY:_customMaxX customLengthY:_customYLength];

    }
    //length of range is specified, one can change only the startpoint
    else if (CPTCoordinateX == coordinate) {
        CPTPlotRange* plotRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:_customXLength];
        return plotRange;
    }

    //returning nil is never reached :D
    return nil;
}
```

EDIT:
What I've observed, that when scrolling very accurately only in x, the plots are moving togheter nicely. Only when one scrolls also in Y (even single pixels), it's starting to shake.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it with changing the moment of sending the notification:

```
- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {
        NSLog(@"changing plotRange: %ld",(long)coordinate);
    if (CPTCoordinateY == coordinate) {
        return [self automaticYRangeWithCustomMinY:_customMinY CustomMaxY:_customMaxY customLengthY:_customYLength];
    }
    else if (CPTCoordinateX == coordinate) {
        if (_postNotifications) {

            NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:newRange, @"newRangeKey",
                                      self.identifier, @"identifierKey", nil];

            NSLog(@"sendingNewRangeNotif");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TODOnotifRangeChanged" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        }

        CPTPlotRange* plotRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:_customXLength];
        return plotRange;
    }

    return nil;
}
```